# Jar for development and War for deployment in gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, jar, spring-boot, war

I am using Gradle build system. I am working in spring boot project. I want to use jar for my development and WAR for the deployment. I have to change my tomcat dependency provided for war. Is it possible to make it auto provided when make war otherwise jar include tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the tomcat dependency as provided. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging).

Also you may need both the main function and the confgure function in the startup class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }
}
```

That way you can run the applciation as a normal java app or deploy it in tomcat.